# What would be the best way to convert input into other keyboard languages?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I recently built an access program where there are accounts for customers at an agency.

The problem is that **lots of their customer's account names are not in english**. this makes it difficult for agents to search because they have to keep changing between the two languages.

I sent them a software I found that enables changing the language after it has been entered (http://langover.com/) but they are not happy with it.

They want me to build them something that will automatically search in both languages.

Below is the code I am using now:

```
Private Sub SearchBox_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Filter = "[USER]" & " like ""*" & me.SearchBox & "*"" 
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

What would be the best way to get two strings according to the two keyboard language setups?

(For example when typing `akuo` you would get results for `akuo` as well as `שלום`)

Comment: Can you just store both encodings in the database?

Comment: 1. That does not solve the issue - it just goes around it.

Comment: 2. What about the 7,000+ users that are already there?
3. when I open new accounts i will still need the same function.

Comment: Then I guess I'm not clear on what you're looking for.  Are you looking for some way to change the encoding of the input strings from the user? What encoding are they reaching your application *in*? What encoding are you using in the database?

Comment: As I explained in my question, the problem is when the keyboard is on one language and the username is in the other then the username has to be retyped in the correct language. what i am looking for is that it find the result even when it was typed in the wrong language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SearchBox_AfterUpdate()
searchstringlang1 = Me.searchbox
searchstringlang2 = Me.searchbox
str1 = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./" & "/'קראטוןםפשדגכעיחלךףזסבהנמצתץ"
str2 = "/'קראטוןםפשדגכעיחלךףזסבהנמצתץ" & "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./"
For n = 1 To Len(searchstringlang1)
If InStr(1, str1, Mid(searchstringlang1, n, 1)) > 0 Then
searchstringlang2 = searchstringlang2 & Mid(str2, InStr(1, str1, Mid(searchstringlang1, n, 1)), 1)
Else
searchstringlang2 = searchstringlang2 & Mid(searchstringlang1, n, 1)
End If
Next
Me.Filter = "[username]" & " like ""*" & searchstring & "*"" or [username]  like ""*" & searchstringlang2 & "*"""
End Sub
```

Obviously you can do this in any language (I picked the language you used in your example) granted that you type both languages in the same order for the two strings [`str1` and `str2`].

Much Luck